# 404 in the backend in updating products/orders

Tags: magento-1.9, error, backend

I am getting `404 Error`in backend on updating products, orders but nothing shows in system.log.

I can access the backend however with no troubles.What can cause this problem and how to fix it?

Comment: Which hosting are you using? Sometimes it happens because of hosting security.

Comment: Hey thanks for the suggestion I'll try to contact them.

Comment: Which hosting you are using? so I can suggest you edits

Comment: I'm using the Siteground hosting service